# Seeking PDF for Formatting Symbols in Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word

Does anyone know where I can find a PDF that has all of Word 2013 hidden formatting symbols? I would like to print it out.

Thanks

Comment: Does it really need to be in pdf? Also do you mean the symbols shown when you toggle viewing the paragraph symbol button?

Comment: Yes, I want to see the symbols via the symbol button. It doesn't have to be in a pdf. I just thought it would be good to have.

Comment: Yes it does help.

Comment: I'll post an answer so your question will be seen as " answered"

Answer (score 1):

[This link](http://word.mvps.org/Faqs/Formatting/NonPrintChars.htm) explains most of the hidden format marks in Word. Although the page looks as old as Windows 98, the same symbols have been used from Word 6.0 till Word 2016.

> **Paragraph marks**
>
> The paragraph mark or pilcrow (¶) represents a paragraph break
>
> **Line breaks**
>
> A right-angle arrow pointing to the left  represents a line break,
>   inserted with Shift+Enter.
>
> **Pagination breaks**
>
> More obvious in their meaning are manual column, page, and Section
>   Breaks.
>
> **Space characters**
>
> In most fonts, and certainly all Windows “core fonts”, a∙ small∙
>   raised∙ dot∙ represents∙ an∙ ordinary∙ space∙
>
> **Tabs**
>
> An arrow pointing to the right → represents a tab character
>
> **Hyphens**
>
> A conditional hyphen (one that is printed only if it falls at a line
>   break, entered with Ctrl+Hyphen) is shown as ¬.
>
> **Cell markers**
>
> In tables you will see one additional character, the universal
>   monetary symbol (¤)
>
> **Hidden text**
>
> Shown as dotted underline below hidden texts
>
> **Coloured underlines**
>
> Denote several information.
>
> **Anchors**
>
> Control floating objects
>
> **Field codes**
>
> Dynamic texts
>
> **Bookmarks**.
>
> Bookmarks are indicated by heavy square gray brackets

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: Thank you for reminding. It's the first time answering using the app so I couldn't write a detailed answer. I'm working on it now